# In terms of good practices, what is the best return value of an update stored procedure

Tags: database, stored-procedures

option 1: an is_success/has_error variable (1 or 0)

option 2: the updated row itself

option 3: the number of rows affected

option 4: a combination of those or others...

we are using the stored procedure for an api function, if that helps deciding

Comment: There is no one true way. It will depend on the application.

When the application code sends an update, it already has updated values. Why should database resend same thing? However, if there is some business logic in the stored procedures that affects some parent or child records, then you might have to consider either sending the whole record back or perhaps just the delta.

Comment: This is very subjective.  The obvious answer is, whatever you need it to.  1 is redundant, there are existing mechanisms to return success/failure, which provide for more than just a 'pass/fail' flag.  2 appears redundant, unless you also returned the 'before' row as well as the 'after'.  3 might be interesting, but I'm not sure how useful it really is.